# New row every 2 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to grab data from my database and list them in html.

HTML:

```
<section class="flex-container">
    <div id="itemlist" class="productlist"></div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
function _getitemlist(arr) {
    var i;
    $("#itemlist").empty();
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var t;
        t = "<div id='btnshowitem" + arr[i].itemID + "'><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].itemImage + "'width= '200'> <br>" + arr[i].itemName + "<br> Price: $" + arr[i].itemPrice + "</div> <br>";
        $("#itemlist").append(t);
    }
}
```

How do i make it so that the items are automatically listed in a 2 by 2 format?
Currently, it looks like this.[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `<td>` if you're not using a `<table>` ?

To make this 2by2 you just need to style it to appears 2by2, it should be like this:

```
function _getitemlist(arr) {
 var i;

 $("#itemlist").empty();


for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var t;
    t = "<a href='#' id='btnshowitem" + arr[i].itemID + "'><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].itemImage + "'width= '200'> <br>" + arr[i].itemName + "<br> Price: $" + arr[i].itemPrice + "</a><br>";
    $("#itemlist").append(t);
}


}
```

*Removed `<td>` from the loop function*

```
.productlist{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.productlist a{
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

*This style will tell to the **productlist** to use flex alignment and all of his items element will no have half of width, so they only will appears two for row*

Answer (score 0):

Try with `%2`above 2 product create new row

```
function _getitemlist(arr) {
  var i;
  $("#itemlist").empty();
  $("#itemlist").append($('<table>').append('<tbody>'));

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var t;
    t = "<div id='btnshowitem" + arr[i].itemID + "'><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].itemImage + "'width= '200'> <br>" + arr[i].itemName + "<br> Price: $" + arr[i].itemPrice + "</div> <br>";
    var pr = $('#itemlist').find('table').find('tbody');
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
      pr.append($('<tr>'));
    }
    pr.find('tr:last-child').append(t);
  }
}
```

**Example**

```js
function _getitemlist() {
  var i;
  $("#itemlist").empty();
  $("#itemlist").append($('<table>').append('<tbody>'));
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var t;
    t = "<td>ssss</td>";
    var pr = $('#itemlist').find('table').find('tbody');
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
      pr.append($('<tr>'));
    }
    pr.find('tr:last-child').append(t);
  }
}
_getitemlist();
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="flex-container">
  <div id="itemlist" class="productlist">

  </div>
</section>
```